# Is it possible to call IronPython from mixed C++/CLI code?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++-cli, ironpython, mixed-mode

I have a native C/C++ project (MSVC2010), which needs to access IronPython scripts. I was able to include C++/CLI code using this [blogpost](http://msmvps.com/blogs/vandooren/archive/2008/09/03/extending-a-native-c-project-with-managed-code.aspx). However, when I add code like this:

```
    ScriptEngine^ engine = Python::CreateEngine();
    ScriptScope^ scope = engine->CreateScope();
```

(taken from http://oldschooldotnet.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/scripting-ccli-with-ironpython-visual.html), the compiler complains that it can't find ScriptEngine. What should I include? Are the IronPython classes actually available for C++/CLI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure your project has the appropriate references.  This would include  `Microsoft.Scripting.Dll` and `Microsoft.Dynamic.dll` (as well as `System.Core.dll`).

Once you do that, you'll need to add the appropriate namespace `using` statements, as well:

```
using namespace IronPython;
using namespace IronPython::Hosting;
using namespace IronPython::Runtime;
using namespace Microsoft::Scripting;
using namespace Microsoft::Scripting::Hosting;
```

Comment: Thank you. However, it seems I can't add these references as long as I haven't set /CLR for the whole project, is that right? Unfortunately, that is not an option.

Comment: Found a work-around. When I first enable /clr for the whole project, I can add the references. After that I disable /clr for the whole project. I will continue to test the answer now.

Comment: It works, thanks! I did not need the reference Microsoft.Dynamic, but I had to add IronPython and IronPython.Modules.